# Did arXiv.org change its compiler recently? TikZ pictures broken

Tags: tikz-pgf, arxiv

A year and a half ago (29 Apr 2019) I uploaded a tex file to arxiv.org, and it compiled successfully. The document is online and it looks fine. It contains several basic TikZ pictures, for example

[image]

Today I wanted to update the file. Before changing the file, I tried to reupload it to make sure everything was working ok. Arxiv claims to compile the file successfully but, to my surprise, the figures are now not rendered:

[image]

Also, the hyperref links are no longer clickable, e.g.

[image]

vs.

[image]

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,mathrsfs,microtype,tikz}
\usepackage[
 colorlinks=true,
 linkcolor=blue,
 urlcolor=blue,
 citecolor=red,
 pdfstartview=FitV,
 linktocpage
 ]{hyperref}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,maxbibnames=99, minbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

(There are also a couple of `renewcommand`s and `DeclareMathOperator`s)

To be clear, both compilations refer to the exact same tex file.

Is this just an issue with the preview? Or will these problems remain in the final version?

Did arxiv change its compiler since then? (I have uploaded other files recently, with no problems). Should I get in contact with arxiv directly? Or is this something I can fix myself?

Comment: arxiv uses texlive 2020 now, but without some code it is not possible to say if this is the source of your problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would a copy of the log file help? here are the links: https://pastebin.com/aJngAYV9, https://pastebin.com/K5c06ezt, https://pastebin.com/ANJWpPrd (broken into three, too long for a single file)

Comment: oh come on, did you never look at them? You get tons of warnings and even an error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sure, that's my issue: there were no errors or warnings the first time I compiled this file. And it is the same file! So my question is, what recent changes in the compilation engine broke my file? Are there any workarounds? (BTW, the file also compiles just fine locally, with no errors or important warnings).

Comment: well at first remove \pdfoutput=1. Confusing the compilation by changing the output method in the middle of the preamble is not a good idea.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, it seems that was the problem! It's funny because in the past, I was not able to compile files on arxiv without that command (which was recommended by arxiv itself, see https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex). And now it is the other way around! Anyway, thank you for your help :-)

Comment: @Delmastro It does say "setting the flag \pdfoutput=1 within the first 5 lines of the preamble".  I normally do it on the very first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `\pdfoutput=1` after loading tikz and hyperref. Depending on the compilation method used this can heavily confuse the compilation.

`\pdfoutput` should normally not be set in a document, or only at the very begin.

Comment: should we delete the comments below the OP? it seems they were a bit of a red herring

Comment: For arXiv's automatic TeX compilation to know that it should use `pdflatex`, I believe you need to include `\pdfoutput=1` in the first few lines of the file.  Otherwise it uses `latex`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch That is one of the exceptions and for it applies the "only at the very begin" principle. If you change pdfoutput you must ensure that every code that cares about it sees the same value.